# How to access resource on disk in MVN project?

Tags: java, maven

Given location of the file

```
   /Users/me/repo/project_name/src/test/resources/some_dir/some_file
```

From the project itself, i'd like to reference the file relative to `resource` directory.

In other words i'd like to say things like

```
   sourceFile = Utils.readFileAsList("resources/some_dir/some_file");
```

How can i figure out my project's home, so that i can prepend the above path with it, making it `/Users/me/repo/project_name/src/test/resources/some_dir/some_file`

Comment: Are you trying to do this as part of the build or from your application code? Your example looks like the latter, in which case you should be using `ClassLoader.getResource()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't. Use something like `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` instead -- that's what they're for.

For example,

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("some_dir/some_file");
//Read character data from the file
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
String first = bis.readLine();
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

try using getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/some_dir/some_file")